# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in jQuery

Tags: jquery

My jQuery code that causes the error is :

```
$.post($("#list").attr('action'), data, function(json)
{
    if(json.listArr.length>0)
    {
        $.each(json.listArr, function() {
            var $tr = $('<tr>', {
                class   : "catHead",
            });
            var $td = $('<td>', {
                colspan : 11,
                text    : this.category
            });
            $("#listDB").append($tr.append($td));

            $.each(this.value, function() {
                var $tr = $('<tr>',{
                    class : "data"
                });

                var $td = $('<td>', {
                    html    : '<input type="checkbox" id="selected[]" value="'+this.id+'" name="selected[]" /></td>'
                });$tr.append($td);
                $td = $('<td>', {
                    text    : this.id
                });$tr.append($td);
                $td = $('<td>', {
                    text    : this.catCount
                });$tr.append($td);
                $td = $('<td>', {
                    text    : this.shop
                });$tr.append($td);
                $td = $('<td>', {
                    text    : this.item
                });$tr.append($td);
                $td = $('<td>', {
                    text    : this.qnty
                });$tr.append($td);
                $td = $('<td>', {
                    text    : this.unit
                });$tr.append($td);
                $td = $('<td>', {
                    text    : this.price_based_on
                });$tr.append($td);
                $td = $('<td>', {
                    text    : this.mrp
                });$tr.append($td);
                $td = $('<td>', {
                    text    : this.sellers_price
                });$tr.append($td);

                var formattedDate = new Date(this.last_updated_on);
                var d = formattedDate.getDate();
                var m =  formattedDate.getMonth();
                m += 1;  // JavaScript months are 0-11
                var y = formattedDate.getFullYear();
                var date = (d<10?"0":"")+d+"-"+(m<10?"0":"")+m+"-"+y;
                $td = $('<td>', {
                    text    : date
                });$tr.append($td);

                $("#listDB").append($tr);
            });
        });
    }
},"json");
```

According to many other questions bearing a resemblance to the name of this question, I should be looking out for two functions recursively calling one another. However, I started deleting sections (of my entire code, of which this excerpt is a part) to find the problem section (this) and it contains only one function. For the life of me, i can't find two functions recursively calling each other. So, what's causing this error?

Here's a part of the JSON data:

```
{
  "listArr": [
    {
      "category": "Fruits",
      "value": [
        {
          "id": "127",
          "catCount": "1",
          "shop": "More",
          "item": "Apples",
          "qnty": "1",
          "unit": "kg",
          "price_based_on": "Kilos",
          "mrp": "90.00",
          "sellers_price": "90.00",
          "last_updated_on": "2016-12-03"
        },
        {
          "id": "128",
          "catCount": "2",
          "shop": "More",
          "item": "Oranges (Nagpur)",
          "qnty": "1",
          "unit": "Piece",
          "price_based_on": "Piece",
          "mrp": "8.00",
          "sellers_price": "8.00",
          "last_updated_on": "2016-12-03"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: While this is not an answer, you really might want to consider a template framework such as handlebars for something like this, you could do it in a lot less, more readable and testable code.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney could you rewrite this code using said framework?

Comment: Yeah easily, and use something like moment. js to condense all that date stuff into one line probably - have a read and try it and come back if you get stuck

Comment: Can you add the ajax response (the JSON) to the question, so we could try to debug it.. This kind of error mostly happen on infinity loop

Comment: @MoshFeu Added some of the json data. The entire data is huge, but follows the same format.

Comment: `The entire data is huge` - maybe that's the problem. `Maximum call stack size exceeded` thrown when you reached the stack limit: http://www.2ality.com/2014/04/call-stack-size.html. Try to return this JSON exactly and see if the error still thrown.

Comment: @MoshFeu It's not that large - only 128 rows of a DB. I've run a similar program with the same data before. Even this program ran, with the same data, but suddenly stopped running as I was coding further. I can't pinpoint what caused the error, or if it was even caused by me.

Comment: Given code snippet and JSON will not cause this issue. Please check other part of code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

I was trying to send data to the server that didn't yet exist. How this caused such an error is not known to me, however it did.

All I needed to do was to insert the line:

```
var data = $("#list :input").serialize();
```

before sending the data using:

```
$.post($("#list").attr('action'), data, function(json)
```